# Lubuntu 15.04 with Silicon 771/671 Graphics Card Higher Res?

Tags: graphics, lubuntu, xorg, 15.04

I have ask a similar question before on [ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/), but this is slightly different. I had ubuntu (unity) and configured it so that the resolution was quite high and it looked perfect. I have now upgraded to lubuntu 15.04, but in the process of upgrading (thus wiping the old system), I lost all the progress I had made with both xorg and vesa. I seem to remember that vesa worked best.

I realize that for some reason, there are differences between fixing this problem on ubuntu and lubuntu. I did hear of a `ppa patch` for it, but I think that was for 12.04. There was also the option of disabling hardware acceleration, but that was for 12.04 too.

As 15.04 is the latest thing out, I don't know if anyone will know anyway, but any help will be very welcome :-)

Thank You,

Alex

P.S: My target computer is a Fujitsu Siemens V5535.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly same laptop. There is a video driver, but it works only with xorg version not higher than 1.12. It means that it won't work on Ubuntu higher than 12.04. The driver works well, but without 3D acceleration. It appeared that it is not possible to make this driver for newer versions of xorg, since the adapter does not support some features. I have installed Ubutnu 12.04, it uses unity2d. It will be supported till 2017. I think it is enough for this old laptop. Xubuntu and Lubuntu are not supported that long.

[Here is the driver.](https://github.com/hellnest/xf86-video-sismedia-0.9.1.git)

I saw some indications that it is possible to get correct resolution on newer xorg only using xorg.conf options, but I did not test it and I doubt it works. Maximum what you can get this way is 1024 x 768 resolution, which is not good for this screen. On 12.04 you can get native 1280 x 800.

I suggest installing Ubuntu 12.04.5 and then install the driver like this:

```
sudo apt-get install git xorg-dev mesa-common-dev libdrm-dev libtool 
git clone https://github.com/hellnest/xf86-video-sismedia-0.9.1.git
cd xf86-video-sismedia-0.9.1
./configure --prefix=/usr --disable-static
make
sudo make install
```

I did this a few days ago for a friend of mine. It looks like Ubuntu  [12.04.5 DVD version](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04.5/release/ubuntu-12.04.5-dvd-i386.iso) is with xorg 1.11, and there is no need to roll back from newer HWE stack. And there were no problems at all. To solve some problems with video playback it is needed also to switch output to X11 in VLC and gstreamer.

If you download a release with a newer HWE stack, then you will need to roll it back. If you see that packages like xserver-xorg-lts- are installed, then run

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg
```

and they will be replaced by correct ones.

But these laptops have 2GB of RAM. They were sold with 1, but another 1 has been added. With only 1 GB it should not work quite well. But Lubuntu with the same driver should work. The GUI is not supported any more, but everything else uses same Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: I used xorg.conf at one point. I can't remember if it worked though.

Comment: Have a butchers at my old thread on ubuntuforums:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2244408

Comment: Is `make` (penultimate line of code) a separate command or is is part of the line before it? =)

Comment: Make is a separate command. I added a note about RAM size. Please consider it too. And this driver won't install on anything but 12.04. It is good that 12.04.5 is shipped with xorg 1.11, not with newer HWE stack.

Comment: I only have 1GB. I'm not sure what you meant in you note in the answer, but just to clarify, is it still OK to do all of this with only 1GB?

Comment: Yes, it is still OK. But the system may be slow. 1GB is barely enough to use it. With 2GB it works OK. There is an option to use lubuntu 12.04, but it will be only partially supported. Lubuntu softwate centre will not work, etc.

Comment: Try to install Ubuntu and see how it works. Modern browsers require a lot of ram. But you can try to use something more lightweight.

Comment: Does the software center still work in 12.04? I'm just asking that to clarify whether it only stops working if you apply the fixes that you suggested.

Comment: In Ubuntu it still works. The system is supported. Lubuntu software center of 12.04 does not work, but you can install Ubuntu software center to lubuntu.

Comment: Sounds complicated.

Isn't there another fix I could try?

Comment: It is not complicated. Just run "sudo apt-get install software-center" in lubuntu. And there is no other fix.

Comment: OK. So I need to install 12.04 and run that code you gave me, and install the software center? 

And the ppa patch was for 13.04. If that works, does the software center work in 13.04?

Comment: If you install Ubuntu 12.04, then you do not need to install Software Center. It is needed only for lubuntu. You can install xubuntu, where software center works. I do not know what ppa patch you are talking about.

Comment: This laptop is too slow to run ubuntu, I hate XDE and you can find the ppa patch at http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2215422&p=12979209#post12979209. Either I use lubuntu, or I do nothing. =)

Comment: **OK, I have made a `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/use-vesa.conf` file. The resolution is MUCH better. It's now at 1024x768. I'd like it higher. I'm going to look around and see if there's a way to do that. If you have any suggestions, let me know =)**

Comment: You won't get better with new xorg. I gave you all directions to get it higher.

Comment: Yeah, but I don't want to have to move down to 12.04 and faff around with the software center and whatever else. I want it to just work. And currently, it is doing just that! Plus, I used vesa before, and I got the highest res possible on my screen dimensions.

Comment: Your screen is 1280x800. If you are happy with 1024x768 then no problem.

Comment: No, I'm not happy with 1024x768 =D hahahahaha, that's the whole point of my _ehem_, 'answer'.

Comment: So on the theme of the comment I made on that other thread, is there any way to get vesa to a better resolution? If you have a decent answer please, give us a shout. And this doesn't just go to @Pilot6, this goes to anyone who reads this =) Meanwhile, I'll be looking through my old thread on ubuntuforums. I seem to remember something about blacklisting... =D

Comment: I managed to get it up to 1280x768, but edited the xorg file wrongly. Is there any way to edit the file again but without even loading UI and staying in GRUB/text interface? Like F8 or something. I forget. There was something you could use in ubuntu, I'm sure.  Thanks.